# HtmlAgilityPack issue with HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to get title, image src and other details but here is an issue

```
<div class="thumb-container">
    <a class="featured" title="Spectacularly " href="http://www.site.com"></a>          
    <div rel="0" id="property_image_1181140" class="thumb">
        <a title="*Want this title*" href="*http://www.wanttogetthislink.com*">
           <img style="width: 190px; height: 127px; left: -11px; top: 0px;" alt="Spectacularly upgraded 5 bed Family Villa For Sale" src="http://c1369013.r13.cf3.rackcdn.com/1181140-1-mini.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
<div class="description-listing">
   <div class="heading">
      <div class="type">
         <label>*5,900* sq.ft.,</label>
         <span>*Villa*</span>
         <p class="bedroom"><em>*5*</em></p>
         <p class="bathroom"><em>*6*</em></p>
      </div>
      <p class="amount">
         <label>AED</label>
         <strong>*5,120,000*</strong>
      </p>
   </div>
```

Here is my code

```
 var allCarResults = rootNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='general-listing']");
 foreach (var carResult in allCarResults)
 {
     var dataNode = carResult.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='thumb']");
     var carNameNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//a");
 }
```

Here i want to get everything in **

i do not know how to do that..

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're after... Can you highlight the items you'd like and based on which anchor?

Comment: @jessehouwing: I enclosed in ** every thing i needed..now i hope you are clear

Answer (score 0):

The principle is pretty much the same, you'll need to write an XPath for each item and select it from a common anchor:

```
HtmlNode thumbContainer = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='thumb-container']");

HtmlNode link = thumbContainer.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='thumb']/a");
string linkTitle = link.Attributes["title"].Value;
string linkHref = link.Attributes["href"].Value;

HtmlNode label = thumbContainer.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='description-listing']/div[@class='heading']/div[@class='type']/label");
string labelText = label.InnerText;

// ... Similar for other items
```

Alternatively you could iterate through each HtmlNode and its children, then for each item match it against a list of items you're after.

Comment: Here it give me object refrence null error "string labelText = label.InnerText;"

Comment: Then your html is not exactly what you posted.

Comment: Post the real data or a link to to that site. Also, if the label is optional, make sure you add `if (HtmlNode != null)` around the assignment to check against that